# Making a Method Globally Accessible in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

given i have the following block of code

```
(function(){    
    var mb = {
        abc:function(){
            //do something
        },
        xyz:function(width, height, site){
            //do something
        }
    };
})();
```

how do i make the method `mb.abc` accessible from the page, but not `mb.xyz`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var mb = function() {
    function xyz(width, height, site){
        // not visible outside
    }

    return {
        abc:function(){
            //do something
        }
    };   
}();
```

mb.abc() is public, but mb.xyz() is not.

Comment: i get `mb.abc() is not a function` in firebug